# Get a point that's 25% of the screen size in Android

Tags: java, android

I use an android Studio [Library](https://github.com/dimorinny/show-case-card-view/) that requires me to use a pointF when using a position. For the Y value I just use max screen size. For the x value I would like it to be 25% of the screen size, how do I do this?
This is what I have right now:

```
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    new ShowCaseStepDisplayer.Builder(getActivity())
    .addStep(new ShowCaseStep(new Position(new PointF(510, size.y)), "Based upon the information you've provided, we've selected certain articles for you"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply calculate value, like `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.25`

Comment: How would I put this in a Point?

Comment: new Point((int)getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.25, size.y)

Comment: It says: PointF (float, float) in PointF cannot be applied to (double, int)

Comment: then new PointF((float)getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.25, (float)size.y)

Comment: @RahulGaur what kind of information do you need? 25% of screen size is quarter of screen width, i.e `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.25`

Comment: All these comment information in your answers as an update, comments are only for minor details